# Check if certain props changed, no indexer

Tags: typescript

I am using TS 2.4 -

I have an object defined by interface:

```
interface Foo {
   name: string,
   version: number,
   qux: boolean,
   baz: boolean
}
```

I do not want an indexer in here. I now want to do a `.some` to see if certain props changed. These props are defined as strings in an array.

```
const significantProps = ['name', 'version'];

const foo: Foo = {};
const prevFoo: Foo = {};
const shouldUpdate = significantProps.some((prop: string) => foo[prop] !== prevFoo[prop]);
```

However this gives me error:

> [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Foo' has no index signature. [7017]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If you want to index things, you'll need an indexer. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine that array of keys to actually be an array of `keyof Foo`:

```
const significantProps: (keyof Foo)[] = ['name', 'version'];

const foo: Foo = {} as any;
const prevFoo: Foo = {} as any;
const shouldUpdate = significantProps.some((prop) => foo[prop] !== prevFoo[prop]);
```

Comment: So cool!! I couldn't find `keyof` in the docs. May you please link me? I was looking for all the helper things like this in the docs, is there somewhere?

Comment: Sure, they’re over here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types (scroll down to Index Types).

Comment: Thanks you @y2bd!